# How do I rewrite these URL's?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I'm working on an ancient (1989!) website which, back in the days, just showed a file directory in some cases. I want to use rewrites to show people a proper file instead.

Case: I have 3 folders, 01, 02 & 03. Each of these contains magazine pages, but no index file. Now I would like to redirect people going to /01/ to /01/0101.htm instead, (and /02/ to /02/0201.htm & /03/ to /03/0301.htm )

My knowledge of regex sucks/blows... I tried the following, but that doesn't work:

```
rewrite /01/ /01/0101.htm ;
rewrite /02/ /02/0201.htm ;
rewrite /03/ /03/0301.htm ;
```

What is the proper way to handle these redirects?

Comment: `(1989!)` Given that the first web browser was available internal at CERN in 1990 and only published in 1991,  I somewhat doubt this number is correct :)

Comment: You're totally right :)
The magazines on the site are from '89-'94, but I guess the site was made in later days.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following:

Instead of a rewrite, just define an index per directory:

```
location /01 {
    index 0101.htm;
}
...
```